VBA Excel. Like
How does the Like function work with variables?
For example,
There is one table where A1 = apple, orange, banana, A2 = mango, avocado, pineapple
There is another table where C1 = banana, C2 = apple, C3 = orange.
I need something like:
For Each list_of_fruits In Workbooks(xxx).Worksheets(xxx).Range("....")
   For Each fruit In Workbooks(yyyy).Worksheets(yyyy).Range("...")
      If list_of_fruits Like fruit Then….


As a result, the loop just doesn't work.

Add wildcards to the fruit-variable: If list_of_fruits Like "*" & fruit & "*" Then

If you have a value in a variable and want to use the like-operator, the search string (your fruit) need to contain wildcard characters. For details of that, have a look to the documentation - in our case, that's the *.
So let's play around a little bit. We create a function IsInList that checks if a value (your fruit) is part of a list.
Function isInList(fruit As String, list As String) As Boolean
    isInList = (list Like "*" & fruit & "*")
End Function

An alternative to the like-operator could be to use the InStr-command suggested by Dominique:
    isInList = (InStr(list, fruit) > 0)

or, to make it case insensitive (Upper and Lower characters doesn't matter):
    isInList = (InStr(1, list, fruit, vbTextCompare) > 0)

Let's check it using it as an UDF in Excel:

OK, works.
Oh, wait: apple is not part of the second list, why is E3 displaying TRUE? Because apple is part of pineapple, and our current logic just checks if a string is part of another string.
If we want to check a fruit against every single word in the list, we first have to create a list of single words. In VBA, you do this easily with the Split-command.
Function isInList2(fruit As String, list As String) As Boolean
    Dim fruits() As String, i As Long
    fruits = Split(list, ",")
    For i = LBound(fruits) To UBound(fruits)
        If Trim(fruits(i)) = fruit Then
        ' Or, Case insensitive:
        ' If StrComp(Trim(fruits(i)), fruit, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            isInList2 = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function



What about InStr? Hereby an example:
b1 = InStr(1, "Apple and banana", "Apple", vbTextCompare)
b2 = InStr(1, "Apple", "Apple", vbTextCompare)
b3 = InStr(1, "Banana", "Apple", vbTextCompare)

Result: b1 and b2 are 1, b3 is zero.

I believe this should have been shared as feedback with a comment. However, since comments don’t properly format code, I’m posting it as an answer instead.
This approach includes an option to avoid matching apple with pineapple. Some lines of code are adapted from FunThomas’s post.
Function isInList3(fruit As String, _
                    list As String, _
                    Optional sDelimeter As String = ",") As Boolean
    list = sDelimeter & list & sDelimeter
    fruit = sDelimeter & fruit & sDelimeter
    isInList3 = (InStr(1, list, fruit, vbTextCompare) > 0)
End Function

Sub Test()
    Debug.Print isInList3("apple", "apple,orange,banana")
    Debug.Print isInList3("apple", "mango,avocado,pineapple")
    ' list contains blanks
    Debug.Print isInList3("apple", "mango, avocado, pineapple", ", ")
End Sub


Will fail if list contains blanks (see OPs example data): isInList3("apple", "apple, orange, banana") will return True but isInList3("banana", "apple, orange, banana") will return False as the string ",banana," is not a substring of the list.

If list contains blanks, the third argument should be used. isInList3("apple", "apple, orange, banana", ", ") isInList3("apple", "mango, avocado, pineapple", ", ")
